# VBA dynamically format on dynamic set names

Tags: excel, vba

On Excel I have a list of *n* inputs. From Name 1 to Name n. These have a dynamical defined name from "Name_1" to "Name_n" I would like to do:

if control is yes, then all of them are available, if the control is no the one from 3 to n are disabled (in the sense that their background color is grey). I cannot use conditional formatting because I do not know how long the series of Inputs will be.

The part to check whether the control is yes or no is fine so I will just consider the one where I have checked that the control is no.

I would like to do something like this:

```
if control=no Then
for name in name_3,...,name_n '(since I do not know how much n is, I would loop until I get an error that name_(n+1) does not exist)
Range("Name_3").Interior.Color=gray
```

But in particular I have difficulties in **(a)** looping over the defined names until I get an error **(b)** format the cell on its defined name

[image]

Comment: You can probably use conditional formatting by just applying it to a range larger than the maximum possible number of names; and using code that includes that the name exists.  And for VBA, you can probably use a `For ... each` loop.

Comment: Could you show it more in detail?

Comment: What about the conditional formatting recommedation do you not understand?

Comment: How can I include the control that the defined variable exists in the conditional formatting specific for each cell from 1 to n (where I do not know n)?

Comment: What is the maximum `n` that might possibly exist?

Comment: Actually the user can add how many Input as he likes. Even if probably it won't be higher than 100

Answer (score 0):

Given your setup above, apply the following conditional formatting to cells b7:b100 (or go down to b1000 if you like).

```
Rule 1:  =OR(AND(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("Name",$A7)),$C$4="Yes"),AND(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("Name",$A7)),COUNTIF($A$7:A7,"Name*")<=2))

Rule 2:  =AND(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("Name",$A7)),$C$4="no")
```

And be sure to check `Stop if True` for Rule 1

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thanks. What if I do not have Name1, Name2, ... but only 1,2... can it be used the same way?

Comment: You just need to replace just the `Search` portion of the formulas with a formula that will return `TRUE/FALSE` depending on whether there is a name in column A.  That might be as simple as testing for a blank, but since your example is obviously not realistic, you will need to figure that out yourself.  I also suggest you put the formulas into a worksheet cell, and evaluate them so you can understand exactly what they are doing, before you try to apply/modify them.